# Vibe.d HTTPRequest with proxy

Tags: d, vibed

I'm trying to use proxies for http requests with the vibe.d library like this:

```
HTTPClientSettings settings = new HTTPClientSettings;
settings.proxyURL = URL.parse("http://gb.smartproxy.com:30000");
auto response = requestHTTP("https://dlang.org", (scope req) {
    req.method = HTTPMethod.GET;
}, settings).bodyReader.readAllUTF8;

writeln(response);
```

As soon as I enable the proxy settings I get errors like this on pretty much every site I try with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://dlang.org/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

It works fine when I do it in python with the requests library with the same proxies

Comment: can you do more verbose logging with the python library? i wonder if it automatically follows the redirect and vibe doesn't or something like that (though it sure seems super weird that it wold spit out a 302 redirect for that request, it is just the first thing i'd wanna check)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe why would it work without a proxy then though? as soon as i remove the settings argument it works. i also tried proxys with std.net.curl instead and it works. i think this is a bug inside vibe.d

Comment: yeah probably, just still comparing the network traffic of vibe vs it of python would help point to just where the bug is